# iOS - Localized string doesn't work in pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working on creating 2 new pods for my company, but one of them decides to act up and doesn't localize strings at all, instead, it returns the keys.
They have pretty much the same podspec for both (I simply clone one and change the name).
I set a break point and tried to print out the Bundle `po Bundle(path: path)`, this is what I got:

```
- some : NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/62C0534D-6CRE-40AE-9C2A-574BF212A4AE/AppName.app/PodName.bundle/en.lproj> (not yet loaded)
```

Print out the string with this: `po Bundle(path: path)?.localizedString(forKey: key, value: "", table: table) ?? ""` gives me the value of `key` (table = PodName).

Print out the resource path `po Bundle(path: path)?.path(forResource: "PodName", ofType: "strings")` gives me nil (the string file name is the same as pod name). The other pod I have has a valid path for the resource.

I check on the other pod, see everything is exactly the same, except for the pod name, and it works. Other teams' pods use the same pattern to localize strings as well and they all work. If I put the `strings` extension into resource_bundles, it won't load the first time, but if I load the screen again, correct strings will show up.

In the main project I can even see the strings files get downloaded into Resource folder of the pod.

Here is the podspec that I have:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  # ―――  Spec Metadata  ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  spec.name         = "PodName"
  spec.version      = "20.7.1"
  spec.summary      = "PodName"
  spec.description  = <<-DESC
PodName
                   DESC

  spec.homepage     = "example.com"

  # ―――  Spec License  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  spec.license      = { :type => "GNU GPLv3", :file => "LICENSE" }


  # ――― Author Metadata  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  spec.author             = { "My Name" => "my.email@example.com" }

  # ――― Platform Specifics ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  spec.platform     = :ios, "10.0"

  # ――― Source Location ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  spec.source       = { :git => "the git url", :tag => "#{spec.version}" }

  # ――― Project Settings ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  spec.requires_arc = true
  spec.static_framework = true

  spec.subspec 'Core' do |sp|
    sp.source_files  = "PodName", "PodName/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    sp.public_header_files = "PodName/**/*.h"
    sp.preserve_paths = 'PodName/**/*.lproj/*.strings'
    sp.resource_bundles = {
      'PodName' => ['PodName/**/*.{lproj,storyboard,xib,xcassets,json,imageset,png}']
    }
  end

  spec.subspec 'Device' do |sp|
    sp.dependency 'PodName/Core'
    sp.vendored_frameworks = "Device/FrameworkA.framework","Device/FrameworkB.framework"
  end

  spec.subspec 'Simulator' do |sp|
    sp.dependency 'PodName/Core'
    sp.vendored_frameworks = "Simulator/FrameworkA.framework","Simulator/FrameworkB.framework"
  end

spec.dependency 'A'
spec.dependency 'B'
spec.dependency 'C'
spec.dependency 'D'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Target Membership for Localized file with your Framework?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't really know what is Target Membership for Localized file. :)

Comment: I mean Target like this:
[example](https://miro.medium.com/max/2916/1*oQ-aCQd3we1TCTkMLH0iIw.png)

Comment: These belong to pod so cocoapod should import them correctly. Now I notice that none of the strings files in pods has target membership section. strings files in the main project have it, but this shouldn't be an issue since other pods' strings are translated correctly